# Remove empty directories using msbuild

Tags: msbuild

How can I process a path recursively so that once the processing completes there are no empty directories under the path.

For example, say we have `C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3` and there are no files in any of these directories. The outcome should be the removal of all three directories.

I would like to accomplish this without the use of custom tasks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should work, didn't check the performance of counting thousands of files though just to get array length...

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Foo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Foo">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Directories Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('D:\foo', '*', System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />
            <Directories>
                <Files>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("%(Directories.Identity)", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).get_Length())</Files>
            </Directories>
        </ItemGroup>        
        <RemoveDir Directories="@(Directories)" Condition="%(Files)=='0'" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. A directory that contains a directory that contains files must not be deleted. See the precise text concerning recursion, etc. in the first line of the OP.

Comment: A directory that contains a directory that contains files will not be deleted because file count for such directory with AllDirectories option will not be 0.

Comment: Ahhh, I wasn't paying attention to the `AllDirectories` part. Somewhat inefficient for deeply nested trees containing lots of files deep in the tree, but I doubt that would usually be a problem in practice. I find it rather elegant, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using an `Exec` Task running PowerShell:

**MSBuild**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DefaultTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CleanPath>C:\MyDirAboveDir1</CleanPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="DefaultTarget">
        <Exec Command="PowerShell .\RemoveDir.ps1 '$(CleanPath)'" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**PowerShell** *RemoveDir.ps1*

```
Param ([string]$folderpath = $(throw "provide folderpath"))

$folders = Get-ChildItem $folderpath -recurse -force | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}

if ($folders -ne $null)
{
    [array]::Reverse($folders)

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
        Write-Host "Examining contents of $($folder.fullname)"
        $childitems = Get-Childitem $folder.fullname -recurse -force | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }

        if($childitems -eq $null)
        {
            "Remove folder: " + $folder.FullName
            Remove-Item $folder.FullName -Recurse -Force
        }
        else
        {
            Write-host "Files found in $folder, skipping delete"
        }

        $childitems = $null
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "no sub folders found"
}
```

---

*Courtesy to [Guy Ellis Rocks: Powershell script to remove empty directories](http://guyellisrocks.com/powershell/powershell-script-to-remove-empty-directories/)*

Comment: Not really what I was looking for (taking a dependency on a file outside the msbuild file) but thanks. Might come in handy someday, as I use PowerShell sometimes too.